# Back and forward button change image in ImageView

Tags: android-layout, android-imageview

i want to change the image in an image view when the user clicks next also i want to go back to the previous image when the user clicks back. does anyone have any examples of this? or code to make this possible?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You got the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)
method , use it.

Comment: by clicks next i mean a button which would take the user to the next image

Comment: Yes, you need to implement the click listener of the button take the image view and change it's image source!